# Line chart disable interpolation

Tags: chart.js

Is it anyway to disable interpolation in `line chart` using `chartjs`? I just red entire documentation and didnt find anything about this.

**@UPDATE**

`lineTension: 0` is the thing I was looking for. 
(Thanks @tektiv for the answer)

Comment: What do you mean by "interpolation".  If you are using a line chart, it has to do some kind of interpolation, doesn't it?  Maybe line chart is not what you want.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to edit the `lineTension` property ([*check the documentation*](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-dataset-structure)), stored in the dataset :

```js
datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    lineTension: 0,
    data: [/* ... */],
    // ...
}]
```

Setting it to `0` will prevent the interpolation from working.

You can see the result [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk3vte6x/), and here is a screenshot :

[image]

Comment: 'lineTension' and 'steppedLine' give different results (checked in the jsFiddle), I believe 'lineTension' is what the OP was asking for.